# Company name for ticker symbol

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-datareader

Is it possible to get the company name for the ticker from pandas datareader. Such as i can use this code which will output the data for the company:`data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo',start, end)`. How can i get the ticker name `Fb` for `Facebook`?

If pandas-datareader does not offer this what can i do to get the name of the company?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
import yfinance as yf

pg = yf.Ticker("PG")

print("Short Name: " + pg.info['shortName'])
print("Long Name: " + pg.info['longName'])
```

Result:

`Short Name: Procter & Gamble Company (The)`

`Long Name: The Procter & Gamble Company`

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what i was looking for